# RequiredIf attribute give error when initializing the database the database using EF 5 code first

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the following error when using the RequiredIf attribute in the entity while initializing the database using EF5 code first.

```
System.Data.DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. 
See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException:
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

If I comment the [RequiredIf] attribute code first build the database successfully. Any idea?

[image]

Update:

I step through the debugger and found that it's adding a validation error. How do I switch this off while initializing the database using code first.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the value of the `ApplicationStatus` property?

Comment: what does EntityValidationErrors disclose ?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov the value of ApplicationStatus could be 1, 2, 3 or 4. For IfRequired attribute if the value is 2 then apply the required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occurring during the seeding. The requiredIf validation says if the `ApplicationStatus` is recommended i.e. 2 then the `DecisionDate` is mandatory. So I added the `DecisionDate` property to the seed function in my context and it worked. Thank you everybody to looking at the issue anyway.

Lesson learnt is if you put validation in you domain objects then seed data accordingly.

[image]